Tkinter python : images not loading
everyone! I was making a simple tamagotchi game as a practice but I endountered a problem:

I put the creation of canvas and widgets inside of a method create_widgets of a KimUI class and after that nothing loads or works, when i create everything outside of class it works, but i need it to be within a method of a class
I have no idea howe to update the game's status, i tried to look that up but no results

I want to make sure that when the program is launched,the window looks like this:(https://i.sstatic.net/51yqWX6H.png) also the images mentioned in the code: (https://i.sstatic.net/7TWIlveK.png)
There are 3 buttons to regulate taamgotchi's parameters and a label of text that shows each of attribute's value
I'd appreciate any help or criticism!!! :)
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from random import randrange
from PIL import Image,ImageTk

root = Tk()
root.title("Hamster Kim")
root.geometry("600x500")

class pet(object):

  def __init__(self,name):
    self.name = name
    self.food= (randrange(30,100))
    self.hygiene = (randrange(20,100))
    self.fun = (randrange(20,100))
    self.alive = True

  def pass_time(self): 
    self.food-=5
    self.hygiene-=5
    self.fun-=5

  def check_status(self):
    return f"Hunger:{self.food},/nFun:{self.fun},/nHygiene:{self.hygiene}"
  
  def feed(self):
    messagebox.showinfo("Hamster Kim","*Crunch Crunch* Yummy!")
    self.food+=10
    if self.food < 0 :
      self.food = 0
      messagebox.showinfo("Hamster Kim","I am hungry!!!")
    elif self.food > 100:
      self.food = 100
      messagebox.showinfo("Hamster Kim","I am full!")
    self.pass_time()


  def clean(self):
    messagebox.showinfo("Hamster Kim","Refreshing!")
    self.hygiene+=10
    if self.hygiene < 0 :
      self.hygiene = 0
      messagebox.showinfo("Hamster Kim","I am still dirty")
    elif self.hygiene > 100:
      self.hygiene = 100
      messagebox.showinfo("Hamster Kim","I am clean!")
    self.pass_time()

  def play(self):
    messagebox.showinfo("Hamster Kim","That was fun!")
    self.fun+=10
    if self.fun < 0 :
      self.fun = 0
      messagebox.showinfo("Hamster Kim","I am bored!")
    elif self.fun > 100:
      self.fun = 100
      messagebox.showinfo("Hamster Kim","I've played enough")
    self.pass_time()

class KimUI():
  def __init__(self,master):
    self.master = master
    master.title("Hamster Kim")
    self.init_pet()
    self.init_ui()

  def init_pet(self): #On initialise le tamagotchi
    self.pet = pet("Kim")

  def init_ui(self): #On initialise l'interface
    self.load_sprites()
    self.create_widgets()

  def load_sprites(self): #On garde les images de tamagotchi dans un dico
    self.sprites = {'hungry':PhotoImage(file ="hungry.png"),
                   'sad':PhotoImage(file ="sad.png"),
                   'dirty':PhotoImage(file ="dirty.png"),
                   'happy':PhotoImage(file ="happy.png"),
                   'neutral':PhotoImage(file ="neutral.png"),
                   'dead':PhotoImage(file ='dead.png')}
    
  def create_widgets(self): #pour créer un canvas et des elements
    bg = PhotoImage(file = "bg.png") 
    self.canvas = Canvas(self.master,width = 600,height=500)
    self.canvas.pack()
    self.canvas.create_image(0,0,image=bg,anchor="nw")

    self.sprite_label = Label(self.master,image = self.sprites['neutral'])
    self.sprite_label.pack()

    self.status_label = Label(self.master, text = self.pet.check_status)
    self.status_label.pack()

    feed_icon = PhotoImage(file ='feed_icon2.png')
    clean_icon = PhotoImage(file ='clean_icon2.png')
    play_icon = PhotoImage(file ='play_icon2.png')
    
    self.feedButton = Button(self.master,image=feed_icon,command=self.pet.feed)
    self.feedButton.pack()

    self.cleanButton = Button(self.master,image=clean_icon,command=self.pet.clean)
    self.cleanButton.pack()

    self.playButton = Button(self.master,image=play_icon,command=self.pet.play)
    self.playButton.pack()

    self.canvas.create_window(530,100, anchor="nw", window=self.feedButton)
    self.canvas.create_window(530,180, anchor="nw", window=self.cleanButton)
    self.canvas.create_window(530,260, anchor="nw", window=self.playButton)


 

  def update_sprite(self):
    if not(self.pet.alive):
      self.sprite_label.config(image=self.sprites['dead'])
    elif self.pet.hunger <=10:
      self.sprite_label.config(image=self.sprites['hungry'])
    elif self.pet.fun <=10:
      self.sprite_label.config(image=self.sprites['sad'])
    elif self.pet.hygiene <=10:
      self.sprite_label.config(image=self.sprites['dirty'])
    elif self.pet.food>=60 and self.pet.hygiene>=60 and self.pet.fun>=60:
      self.sprite_label.config(image=self.sprites['happy'])
    else:
      self.sprite_label.config(image=self.sprites['neutral'])
  
  def death_message(self):
    messagebox.showinfo("Hamster Kim","Hamster Kim died...")
    self.disable_buttons()
  def disable_buttons(self):
    self.feedButton.config(state = 'disabled')
    self.cleanButton.config(state = 'disabled')
    self.playButton.config(state = 'disabled')


app = KimUI(root)

root.mainloop()

